# Pygame won't work on Mac mini with no monitor connected

Tags: python, macos, opengl, pygame

I'm making a Makey Makey project, but for the purposes of this question it can be considered as a simple keyboard.

I have made a YouTube video showing the project, I would like the samefunctionnalities, except the screen hack: 
http://youtu.be/98ATkZUR48k

I hooked it up to my kitchen cupboards so when I open one of them it plays a song.

I connected it to my Mac mini and it works OK as long as it has a screen connected. 
When I unplug the screen the songs stop playing.

I have read that the Mac mini loads different graphic drivers based on if there is a monitor connected or not, notably one where OpenGL is not supported.

That is my intuition for why it's not working, but I'm not sure.

So my question is does pygame require OpenGL to run and is there a way to disable it?

The only thing I found were these sort of hardware solutions which for my use case I consider overkill: 
https://macminicolo.net/blog/files/build-a-dummy-dongle-for-a-headless-mac-mini

**Update:**

---

As @Torxed pointed out Pygame relies heavily on OpenGL, so maybe another module or combination of multiple modules would be more useful.

I chose Pygame because I can:

- Easily get keyboard input in a loop
- Play multiple sound files at once
- Be able to pause and resume sound files

Can you recommend a module or a combo of modules that could help me accomplish these two functionnalities easily.

This is the code I am running now with pygame:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.mixer import Sound, Channel

class MakeyCupboard :
    channelIdCounter = 0
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.channelId = MakeyCupboard.channelIdCounter
        MakeyCupboard.channelIdCounter = MakeyCupboard.channelIdCounter + 1
        self.channel = Channel(MakeyCupboard.channelIdCounter)
        self.sound = Sound(fileName)
        self.channel.play(self.sound, -1)
        self.channel.pause()


pygame.init()

dictCupboard = {
    pygame.K_w : MakeyCupboard("rien.ogg"),
    pygame.K_a : MakeyCupboard("train.ogg"),
    pygame.K_s : MakeyCupboard("stronger.ogg")
}

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN :
            try : 
                makeyCupboard = dictCupboard[event.key]
                makeyCupboard.channel.pause()
            except KeyError:
                pass

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP :
            try:
                makeyCupboard = dictCupboard[event.key]
                makeyCupboard.channel.unpause()
            except KeyError:
                pass
```

Comment: Yes afaik Pygame rely on OpenGL, it's mainly a wrapper around it. Once you remove the monitor OSX will disable the rendering engines thus crashing anything trying to use OpenGL. Use one that renders under Cocoa, i think its support in OSX is more flexible. One library using it is https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyGUI

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll look into PyGUI. Pygame just had all the things that I needed in order to get the functionality that I wanted as fast as possible. Right now I'm using a hardware solution : I have a DVI cable connected  to the Mac and the other end of it randomly touching my heater which makes it think it has a monitor connected; not very elegant if I can say so myself. I think it's ridiculous since basically I'm only using sound and my program won't run because of OpenGL :)

Comment: I'd go with another solution all togeather unless you need the graphics at a later point. But even then it might be a separate project all in itself? If you just need a beep, there's also  `sys.stdout.write('\a')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution to your issue if you're only interested in playing a sound:

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE
from time import sleep
audio_file = "/tmp/music.wav"

x = Popen('afplay ' + audio_file, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
while x.poll() == None:
    output = x.stdout.readline() # You need this!
    # Otherwise the output buffer will get full and hang your application.
    # Or just remove stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT from the Popen() call
    # if you're not interested in the output of the application.
    sleep(0.025)    
print('Music stoped')
```

Update:

Since you'd like to pause/switch tracks, either you would need to send command via `x.stdin.write('next\n')` or w/e it is `afplay` takes as commands.

Another solution would be to use one of the libraries found [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic), for instance:

- http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/
- http://www.luga.de/pytone/

By the looks of it PyAudio appears to be simple enough:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

CHUNK = 1024

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)

data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if using this command would allow me to pause and unpause the playing tracks. Also using a python module would seem more elegant . This would be only enough for playing tracks. I'm sorry I didn't mention that in the specs. I made a quick video to show off what the project does and what the problem is. Please check the question for the youtube link.